# When I delete parent child's are not updated Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I delete the parent but in the UI are still the child's and when I manually reload the page the child's are delete too, how it is possible to update or refresh the page when I delete parent, I tried like this but didn't have any function.

```
deleteProject(project, subproject, position, budget) {
const text = 'Are you sure to delete this project ?';
this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, { data: text, disableClose: true })
  .afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    if (result) {
      const subIds = this.project.subProjectIds;
      subIds.splice(subIds.indexOf(subproject.id));
      const posIds = this.subproject.positionIds;
      posIds.splice(posIds.indexOf(position.id));
      this.store.dispatch(new DeleteProjectAction(project.id));
    }
  });
```

}

Here is the reducer and action

```
case DeleteProjectInternalAction.Type:
  return deleteProject(state, action);


function deleteProject(state: BudconState, action: 
DeleteProjectInternalAction): BudconState {
 return {
...state,
projects: state.projects.remove(action.payload)
};
```

}

```
export class DeleteProjectInternalAction implements Action {
static readonly Type: string = 'budcon-item:delete-project-internal';
readonly type: string = DeleteProjectInternalAction.Type;

 constructor(public payload?: string) { }
}

export class DeleteProjectAction implements Action {
static readonly Type: string = 'budcon-item:delete-project';
readonly type: string = DeleteProjectAction.Type;

constructor(public payload?: string) { }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors? Sounds like an exception would be thrown.

Comment: I checked but there is no errors, when i reload the page manually everything is ok.

Comment: How do you deleted it?

Comment: I have reducers at redux and actions. I updated the question you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to make a interval when something is changed to load the store.

```
  deleteProject(project) {
    const text = 'Are you sure to delete this project ?';
    this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {width: '30%',
       data: text, disableClose: true })
      .afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
        this.store.dispatch(new DeleteProjectAction(project.id));
          this.interval = setInterval(() => {  
          //Here define the store to load        
          }, 500);
        } setTimeout(() => {
          clearInterval(this.interval);
        }, 500);
      });
  }
```